# create model from form in django

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

Is there a way to create a model from a form in django(1.5) ?
Like when creating forms from models.

My form is

```
class QuoteForm(forms.Form):

    country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COUNTRIES, required=False)
    street = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
```

And my would be model has exactly the same fields

Comment: I don't think that is the flow of django.  Why can't you create your model first then you can use model form?

Comment: the form was created before the model, i am using a classic model => form + customization for now

Comment: It would make little sense for Django to generate models from forms. Django uses Python metaclasses in the `models.Model` class to handle creating the database access layer. Since this has no visibility into the app's forms, it would not be able to see the model and the tables would not be created. This is why Django goes the other way: Models are relatively static, and forms are derived from them.

Comment: Further, the mapping of form fields to model fields isn't 1:1; a form field could be a text input field, but the corresponding model field could be `CharField`, `TextField`, `IntegerField`, `PositiveIntegerField`, or several others, and you'd have to add a bunch of named parameters to the form definition to tell Django which one to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a simple way to do that using django. This is not a built-in code to do that, but you can study how django make forms from models and try to do it in the reverse way.

Here is the django code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py

Anyway, I think it will better if you create your models first and then use a ModelForm.

Comment: i guess it is the only way to do it (and it works fine so far)